# Deep thought: Levenshtein distance

Tags: code-challenge

So, <s>blatantly plagiarizing from</s> inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53604/code-close-to-the-challenge-sum-of-integers) and its sequel, I thought I'd add another.

The text to match:

> What do you get when you multiply six by nine

The result your function/program/etc. should print or return:

> 42

An online calculator for Levenshtein distance can be found here: http://planetcalc.com/1721/

**Comments are disallowed.**

Comment: Personally, I don't find these challenges very interesting. Most of the time it's near-impossible to have any meaningful overlap with the text, leading to submissions which just leave the excess floating around.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't seen all that many of these myself, though - do they have a tag associated with them, or are they just that bad?

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of the linked challenge because, while not an exact duplicate, it isn't appreciably different.

Comment: This is much too similar, and in much too close succession. If you're going to steal a challenge, at least wait until it's long dead before posting it ;)

Answer (score 7):

## GolfScript, 2

```
What 42 you get when you multiply six by nine
```

All words except `do` are undefined tokens, so they do nothing.

Try it online in [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=V2hhdCA0MiB5b3UgZ2V0IHdoZW4geW91IG11bHRpcGx5IHNpeCBieSBuaW5l).

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 3

Replaces the first character with length(, which is a single TI-BASIC token.

```
length("t do you get when you multiply six by nine
```

Comment: So you're allowed to count the length of your program *after* tokenisation?

Comment: There is no "after tokenization" in TI-83 BASIC; the only way to enrer characters is as tokens.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 10

```
p"What do you get when you multiply six by nine".sum/99
```

In the spirit of the challenge. Following the letter I think the best you can do is

```
p 42||"What do you get when you multiply six by nine"
```

but that program would still work if you changed the string.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 4

```
42 "What do you get when you multiply six by nine
```

That's not a comment, it's a string that doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 3

```
"hat do you get when you multiply six by ni",
```

`,` pushes the string's length.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22hat%20do%20you%20get%20when%20you%20multiply%20six%20by%20ni%22%2C).

Answer (score 0):

### CMD, 9

```
echo 42||What do you get when you multiply six by nine
```

Code after `||` inline will only run if the previous command generates an error.